# Emirates OK to Board

Tags: visas, airports, emirates, ok-to-board

What is OK to Board? This is from Emirates Airlines, https://www.emirates.com/ae/english/help/ok-to-board.aspx

Basically, I was trying to approach them to see if I will be accepted to board a booked flight to Zagreb using a multiple entry C visa issued by Romania (I have used it once). Then, I found this link/form which I did not understand its purpose.

I want to know its purpose and whether, by completing this form, would serve my case?

Alternatively, if the aforementioned does not serve my case, what options you recommend to get confirmation from the airline? Note that I have already obtained a written approval, via email, from the Embassy that I can use the visa to visit Zagreb.

Comment: “Ok to Board” is a process to authenticate UAE visas for some customers from the South Asia subcontinent. It’s not relevant to your situation. I doubt you’ll get confirmation from Emirates prior to check-in given that airline T&C normally state that travel documents are the passenger’s responsibility. Timatic (the system used by airlines) will probably provide the answer but to check that you’ll need to update your question to state your citizenship and your point of origin for the trip.

Comment: _OK to Board_ applies only to certain nationalities. Are you one of those nationalities?

Comment: The page you link to explains itself quite clearly as far as I can see.  The name "ok to board" certainly suggests a more general function, but the explanation on the page makes it clear that it is nonetheless a fairly narrow function.  What is it about the explanation on that page that you find unclear or that prompts you to ask here about it?

Comment: @Traveller Thank you for the answer. I just checked Timatic via Emirates website, entered my nationality, residence and destination, and it shows that I can travel to Croatia on a Romanian visa. So Emirates Airlines check-in staff would use the same portal to allow me boarding right?

Comment: @phoog I can see what is written in that link, however, I had doubts if I can use to attach my documents (passport, visa) to get OK to Board. Now things are clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Ok to Board” is a process to authenticate UAE visas for some customers from the South Asia subcontinent. It’s not relevant to your situation. I doubt you’ll get confirmation from Emirates prior to check-in given that airline T&C normally state that travel documents are the passenger’s responsibility.

You mention in a comment that Timatic (the system used by airlines) shows you have the correct travel documentation to enter Croatia, so you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

From [Quora: What does ECR and ECNR mean on an Indian passport](https://www.quora.com/What-does-ECR-and-ECNR-mean-on-an-Indian-passport), it seems a measure to protect Indian people (and other countries) from being exploited.  It happens on some countries, where people passport is taken away from the company one work, so he become nearly a slave.

If you are required to do it (see the condition) you must obey. You are travelling to Europe, so you should have no problem to get the "OK", but anyway Indian authorities want to check. It doesn't matter if you get automatically the OK, if you are required to apply for the "OK to travel" you must comply it.

Note: this is not about Croatia (and so about your visa), but it is about India or Pakistan permission to travel. Without the OK, Emirates cannot board you. ECR stamp is printed by Indian (or Pakistan) authorities.

Comment: ‘Ok to board’ is primarily a guard against fake visas.  ECR is a different check with a different purpose.

Comment: @Traveller: the document of emirates states that the "OK to board" is needed if you have ECR passport. Requirement 1 and 3. So it is the same check.